# didDetermineState, didEnterRegion, didExitRegion events not called

Tags: ios, geolocation, location, ibeacon

I have a beacon and geofences-based application working correctly for some time.

But after update to xCode 9 and iOS 11, when the users choose the only in use option in the location authorization request alert, these callbacks never fired again.

I undestand that this is the expeted performance in background or with the app closed, but no in foreground.

If the user select the always option, the app works as expected, firing this callbacks.

Any idea why these events are not happening in foreground? Is this the expected performance?

Comment: You see this on a clean install of an app built with XCode 9 onto an iOS 11 device?

Comment: Yes, this behavior occurs on a device with iOS 11 if the user selects the only in use option. Even the application is in the foreground, no callback is triggered. In ios 10, it was not mandatory to offer the option only when using, so we had never encountered this problem.

Comment: @KepaSantos will you please guide me for Geo fence did exit method?

Comment: @Amanpreet Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: @KepaSantos I am working on Geofence. I have set the region with radius 50 meters but strange is I am getting enter pop up while I am 100 meters far from the region and the exit pop up took 300 or more meters to show. Geo-fence is not working as per my requirement of 50 meters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Region monitoring is now only supported with the 'Always' share location permission. Apple outline what is supported and what is not here:

[Location Services Available](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/choosing_the_authorization_level_for_location_services#2916339)

Comment: So what sense does the geofences have after this point?
Is there any way to offer the user only the option of always or never in the authorization alert? Beacons and geofences are irrelevant on only in use mode.

Comment: No you have to offer the user both options from iOS 11 onwards. What you can do is add a notification that pops up warning the user if they don't give 'Always' permission then the app won't work correctly.

Comment: we fear that it is the only option, even if it is not the ideal one. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

**Beacon monitoring is now blocked on iOS 11 if a user chooses "when in use" permission for Location Services and not "always".**   In order to request always permission on **iOS 11 must use new key in their .plist file** called `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription`:

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs to access your location so it can tell when you are near a beacon.</string>
```

Previously, you used this key to get always location access (yet another key was used to request access only when in use):

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs to access your location so it can tell when you are near a beacon.</string>
```

**Both keys are needed if you are targeting iOS 11 as well as earlier versions.**

If you fail to update the .plist to use the new key, then the consequences are different depending on the operating system version and the XCode version used to build the app:

- Built with XCode 8, Run on iOS 10: Prompts for "always" location access.
- Built with XCode 8, Run on iOS 11: Prompts for either "always" or "when in use" location access by user's choice.
- Built with XCode 9+, Run on iOS 10:  Prompts for "always" location access.
- Built with XCode 9+, Run on iOS 11:  **App will not prompt for location permission at all.  Permission not be granted.**

In the last case, if you try to run this app on your phone, the permission request will fail silently, but the following will show up in the log in case you have XCode connected:

`Nov  9 11:14:00 Davids-iPod-touch locationd[60] <Notice>: Authorization value kCLClientAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways requested by ‘com.mycompany.MyAppName’ ignored because not in its allowable mask (1)`

If the user does get the permissions prompt and grants "When in use" instead of "Always" access, the you will be able to use beacon ranging APIs but you will not be able to use beacon monitoring APIs.  (didEnter, didExit, and didDetermineState will not be called.)  This is documented in Table 1 of Apple's docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/choosing_the_authorization_level_for_location_services#2916339).

[image]

The theory behind this change is that Apple is trying to get app developers to allow *limited* functionality if users grant location access only when in use.  The new key for iOS 11 above will allow the user to choose which of the two types of location access the user wants to grant.  If you really don't want to let the user accept the "when in use" option, you can't stop them from picking it.  But you can detect this choice, then pop up a dialog telling them the app won't work, and instruct them to go to settings to change this selection.  You can even make it so the dialog can't be dismissed until they make the change.

Comment: First, thank you for your complete response. We have the plist correctly configured, we have also tried to request only in use the mode  and see what happened, but the callbacks were still not firing.On the other hand, the ranging works correctly with only in use mode.

Comment: It seems that as you comment, the only option is to detect only in use mode and warn the user that the application will not work with all its features correctly.

Comment: the truth is that we do not understand this change very well by Apple, since it is "inviting" the user to select only in use mode, ahead of always. Making it difficult for developers to explain to the user the benefit of this option.

Comment: Understand that in order to get the callbacks to fire when only "in use" has been granted, that the events must happen when your app is open and in the foreground.  Try leaving it open while turning all beacons off.  Keep it open for 30 seconds or more and wait to get a didExit callback.  Then turn on a beacon and wait for a didEnter callback.

Comment: Yes, we try this, with the app opened in foreground, no enter region or exit region is firing with different beacons, or shutting then on or off. In the other side ranging events are firing with the app in foreground correctly. So the app is able to ranging on foreground but can't do monitoring on foreground with only in use mode.

Comment: Sorry, see my edited answer to make this clear.  This is actually a design change in iOS 11.  You are now not allowed to use monitoring APIs if the user grants only "when in use".  This explains why you do not get the callbacks.

Comment: I'm sorry to read that, it was what we feared. Thanks for the help.